# Параметры для split в Java

Tags: java, строки

Как задать параметр для разбиения строки в массив в метод split, чтобы он учитывал и переход на следующую строку и пробел сразу?

А сама проблема в том, что если в строке после слова идет переход на следующую строку и нет пробела, то это слово просто прибавляется к предыдущему как один элемент массива. Сейчас сплит выглядит так: `split(" ")`.

Comment: да хоть так: `s.split("( |\n)")`

зы: осваивайте регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так: `s.split("\\s")`. Таким образом строка разобъется в массив учитывая  символы-разделители `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` из предустановленного класса `\s` . Либо просто нужно перечислить символы-разделители, как предлагал [nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394173/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-split-%D0%B2-java#comment394177_394173).
Документация по [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Дано `String S0="ABCDEFGHIJK"`' как разбить на символы по одному символу, просто по одному?

Comment: `char[] chars = s0.toCharArray();`

Comment: ```String S0="ABCDEFGHIJK";
char[] chars = S0.toCharArray();
 ``` Спасибо, работает.