# Java split() даёт первым элементом пустое значение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Пишу код для считывания следующих строк:

```
4 14
a: 0
b: 10
c: 110
d: 111
```

сам код:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int k = input.nextInt();
int l = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(k);
System.out.println(l);


        for (int i = 0; i <k; i++) {
            String str = input.nextLine();

            String[] list = str.split(": |\\n");
            String sym = str.split(": ")[0];
            String[] code= list[list.length - 1].split(": |\\n");


        System.out.println("symbol: "+ sym);
        System.out.println("code: "+ Arrays.toString(code));


    }
```

Почему-то результат следующий:

```
4
14
symbol: 
code: []
symbol: a
code: [0]
symbol: b
code: [10]
symbol: c
code: [110]
```

Т.е. первый элемент пустой.
Я пытался, разумеется, фиксить проблему. Вот здесь:
[Параметры для split в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394173/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-split-%D0%B2-java)
подсмотрел \\n, \\s тоже пробовал-не помогло.
Пытался substring'ами, тоже ничего хорошего.
Из статей на английском, честно говоря, мало что понял.
Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как решить проблему? (Первым элементом должен быть symbol: a code: [0]).
И как можно избавиться от [] в выводе code? Там без Arrays.toString() вообще нечитаемо выходит.

Comment: А что не получается substing-ами? через indexOf определяете позицию двоеточия, а потом берете (тримируя) то что слева и справа. Ну или можно через StringTokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас там какие-то слишком сложные манипуляции.

Если вы после `nextInt()` читаете строку методом `nextLine()`, вам перед этим нужно один раз вызвать `nextLine()` для перевода каретки на новую строку, иначе будет прочитана пустая строка.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int k = input.nextInt();
int l = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(k);
System.out.println(l);
input.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i <k; i++) {
     String str = input.nextLine();
     String[] list = str.split(":\\s");
     String sym = list[0];
     String code= list[1];
     System.out.println("symbol: "+ sym);
     System.out.println("code: "+ code);
}
```

Вывод:

```
4
14
symbol: a
code: 0
symbol: b
code: 10
symbol: c
code: 110
symbol: d
code: 111
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, затупил.
Воистину так:)

Comment: @TheDoctor Если сработало, пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как решение, галочку поставьте.